# JSON Deserialization in Swift

Tags: json, deserialization, swift

After reading up a bit on collections, I began to wonder if json deserialization was going to be an issue given that collections need to specify a type for the values they contain.  And in the case of dictionaries, one would need to specify the type for both the key and the value.

After a bit of experimentation, I found that the following works:

```
let jsonString = "{\"bool\": true, \"num\": 1,\"string\": \"a string\"}"
let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

let json : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

let valid = NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(json)
```

And when I use a playground (or am in the REPL), I get the following when printing out the contents of the json object:

```
["num": 1, "string": "a string", "bool": 1]
```

My question: is there may be a better way to handle this?

Comment: That's pretty much it, although I would tend to use optionals instead of implicitly unwrapped (? instead of !)  And since it's a lot of arrays and dictionaries of AnyObject, there's a whole lot of casting going on.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest typing your json object a little more:

```
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>
```

This will help you access elements by their key.

Comment: Cannot conver the expression's type '$T4' to type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject!>'